# Regex to check filename extension before upload

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying validate that only a certain file extension is used but the regex I have fails if there are periods in the filename or if there is no extension at all. Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks!

current code:

```
// this looks at what file type was attemped and validates it
$('INPUT[type="file"]').change(function () {
    var ext = this.value.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
    switch (ext) {
        case 'bmp':
        case 'doc':
        case 'xls':
            $('#publicSubmit').attr('disabled', false);
            break;
        default:
            alert('This is and invalid file extension. Vaild extension(s): bmp, doc, xls');
            //$('#publicSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
            this.value = '';
    }
});
```

Comment: Use `\.([^.]+)$/` instead to handle files with periods in their name.

Comment: I don't think you can change value of a file input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not depending on Regex, you could simply use:

```
var ext = value.split('.').slice(-1)[0];
```

to get the files extension.

Comment: `value.length-1` - are you sure?

Comment: `.slice(-1)` would return an array, so additional `[0]` is required